# Names not resolved

Tags: router, dns, arch-linux, fritzbox

Yesterday I connected my computer (Arch) to a new WLAN, browsing without any problem at all.
Today, same computer, same WLAN, I can't browse anymore: the names are no longer resolved. Other devices on the same network can browse. I tried to connect my computer to my Android hotspot and it worked.

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known

$ dig google.com  
; <<>> DiG 9.13.3 <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 34550
;; flags: qr rd ra cd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; MBZ: 0x7fe8, udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     97  IN  A   216.58.205.142

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.178.1#53(192.168.178.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 17 16:12:12 CET 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55
```

I also tried to set custom DNSs to my `/etc/resolv.conf`, with no changes.

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 1.0.0.1
```

The router is a FRITZ!Box 7170, I'm not able to find any DNS related settings.